# For designing dynamic layout in android like the status bar in the home screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gesture

How to make a layout in android like **the status bar in the home screen** which allows the user to drag the status bar up to any height. The layout should also allow the user with a flick up or down to expand or contract the the layout fully.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like a `SlidingDrawer`?

[image]

[image]

Can be used like this:

/src - **SliderActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener;

public class SliderActivity extends Activity {
    Button slideHandleButton;
    SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        slideHandleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideHandleButton);
        slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);

        slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                slideHandleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrowdown);
            }
        });

        slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                slideHandleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrowup);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

/res/layout - **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom">
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
            android:background="@drawable/arrowup"></Button>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center|top" android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="#505050" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="8" android:text="Hello Slider"></TextView>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Do anything"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

You need 2 images in your /res/drawable folder to make it work, like `arrowup.png` and `arrowdown.png` in this example

Comment: I tried Sliding Drawer, but the resizing or flicking of sliding looked to be fixed. I want a layout where i can drag the layout up or down to expand or contract ,just like we can drag the status bar  in the home screen up to any height. Can i use Sliding Drawer with gesture detector to achieve that.